# how to join two queries in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I want to join these two queries.

I want the columns `FulliteName`, `text`, `BeginningBalance`, `QuantityReceived`,`DOS`,`Loss`, `RequestedQuantity` .

I tried the following query. But only the first part is executed.

```
SELECT CI.ItemID,
    FullItemName,
    iub.UnitOfIssueID,
    us.TEXT
FROM Commodity.ItemRRFGroup CI
INNER JOIN dbo.vwGetAllItems y
    ON y.ID = ItemID
INNER JOIN ItemUnitBase iub
    ON y.ID = iub.ID
INNER JOIN UnitOfIssue us
    ON iub.UnitOfIssueID = us.ID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT RD.RequestID,
        y.RRGroupID,
        y.PeriodID,
        ItemID,
        CONCAT (
            Convert(DATE, StartDate),
            ' to ',
            Convert(DATE, EndDate)
            ) Period,
        BeginningBalance,
        QuantityReceived,
        DOS,
        Loss,
        RequestedQuantity
    FROM RRF.RequestDetail RD
    INNER JOIN RRF.Request y
        ON y.RequestID = RD.RequestID
    INNER JOIN RRF.Period x
        ON x.PeriodID = y.PeriodID
    INNER JOIN OrderDetail o
        ON o.OrderID = y.orderID
    ) AS x
    ON CI.ItemID = x.ItemID
```

Comment: what exactly you want? sample data and expected output?

Comment: Do you mean you also want the columns from "SELECT RD.RequestID" etc in the result?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you change this:

```
Select 
   CI.ItemID, 
   FullItemName,
   iub.UnitOfIssueID,
   us.text
   .....
```

To this:

```
Select 
   CI.ItemID, 
   FullItemName,
   iub.UnitOfIssueID ,
   us.text,
   x.BeginningBalance,
   x.QuantityReceived,
   x.DOS,
   x.Loss, 
   x.RequestedQuantity
   ....
```

**Update**

If you do not use the alias x of the sub query. Then you are not going to get the columns from x.

Comment: Where `x` is the name of the table/derived-table from your FROM clause that contains the field you want. In other words, if it isn't in your SELECT clause, then it won't be in your results.